# HERE geocode: limit results by continent

Tags: here-api

Is there a parameter that I can add to the search which will limit the results to addresses within Europe or US ?
I'm using js to access the geocoding api, once the end user has typed in *n* characters I'm using that as the search query. So far I have this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let geoCoder = this.platform.getSearchService()

  let geoCodingParameters = {
    q: searchString,
    jsonattributes: 1
  }

  geoCoder.geocode(
    geoCodingParameters,
    (response) => { resolve(response.items) },
    reject
  )
})
```

Which works just fine, but I'd prefer not to show addresses which aren't relevant to the end users' region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the parameter `in` to provide an ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 `countryCode` such as `USA` to limit results to a specific region. For example:

```
let geoCodingParameters = {
  q: searchString,
  in: 'countryCode:USA',
  jsonattributes: 1
}
```

The JS API wraps the Geocoding & Search API. You can check out all parameters in the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html).

Comment: I tried the above, js throws an error because of the syntax. Using ```in:countryCode``` throws an error because the value for 'in' is incorrect. Same if I use ```in:'GBR'```

Comment: My code snippet didn't work because of missing apostrophes around the parameter. I've fixed that. I've tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I'll try that, and thanks btw, really appreciate this.

Comment: You're welcome. btw, it might be helpful to others if you accept the answer as correct.